# C# Entity framework AddOrUpdate error remains?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert / update using AddOrUpdate method. When I get an error while inserting, It remains until I restart the program or remove entity object from entity array.
An error occurred because I have provided a null value to a none nullable property(in DB). And next time I provided the correct value but the error still remains.

```
InnerException = {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Brand_Code_Brand\". The conflict occurred in database \"App\", table \"dbo.Brand\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Is this normal or am I doing it wrong ?

```
            try
            {                
                entities.Brand_Code.AddOrUpdate(brandCode);
                entities.SaveChanges(); // if an error occurred here, It remains -->
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                entities.Brand_Code.Remove(brandCode); // <-- until do this or restart. If I remove this, then I have to restart the program to get rid of this error. 
                throw;
            }
```

Is this a correct way ?

Comment: Read the error. You tried to add a record with an invalid value. The error explains that the value you entered violates the `FK_Brand_Code_Brand` foreign key constraint by usiing a non-existent BrandID. Make sure you either use a valid value, or set the property to NULL. The code you posted isn't really relevant and `entities.Brand_Code.Remove(brandCode)` only covers up the problem

Comment: yes if I try inserting with an invalid object, It remains until I remove it manually. Is that the correct way ? I have a thought like it should remove automatically if an error occured. Am I wrong ?